# Using batch script to read properties file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a properties file located `%ilmhome%\webapp\WEB-INF\amhome.properties`

```
#Tue Feb 15 19:27:14 IST 2011
amhome.connection.password=amhome534
amhome.connection.url=jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@(DESCRIPTION\=(ADDRESS_LIST\=(ADDRESS\=(PROTOCOL\=TCP)(HOST\=diablo)(PORT\=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA\=(SERVER\=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME\=orcl)))
amhome.connection.maxWait=20000
amhome.connection.username=amhome534
amhome.connection.platformId=6
amhome.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

I want to fetch the below items from amhome.properties file into some variables

```
Username        : amhome534
Host            : diablo
Port            : 1521
ServiceName    : orcl
ConnString     : jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@(DESCRIPTION\=(ADDRESS_LIST\=(ADDRESS\=(PROTOCOL\=TCP)(HOST\=diablo)(PORT\=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA\=(SERVER\=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME\=orcl)))
```

How can i do that?

Comment: That's nothing with DOS. DOS is operation system. Batch file is a script framework built-in into Windows. Black window is the console, not a DOS window.

Comment: +1 on that comment, but batch files and most of their syntax still originate with the MS-DOS command processor and CP/M before it. So the legacy is there but there are indeed very, very few actual DOS questions on SO.

Comment: FYI, there's a pre-defined environment variable `USERNAME`, which holds the active user's login name. So maybe you should pick a different name for storing your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [FOR /F command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)... You should be able to set `DELIMS=.=` and `TOKENS=3,*` which would skip 'amhome' and 'connection' but give you value pairs like 'password' + 'amhome534'.

Comment: So far i got this `echo off
setlocal
FOR /F "tokens=3,* delims=.=" %%G IN (c:\simon\amhome.properties) DO ( set %%G=%%H )
echo %password%
echo %username%
endlocal` but how can I fetch `Host, Port and Servicename`?

Comment: Do I see correctly that host, port & username are not properties on their own but need to be dug out of the amhome.connection.url string?

Comment: If so, you could use a combination of [these string manipulation techniques](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php), but (a) offhand I'm still not sure the easiest way, and (b) it won't be easy... but it could be fun. (I have a warped idea of fun, I guess!)

Comment: Yes the the host port and servicename has to be extracted from  within url. I'll give it a try, your link is good, might help me thanks